# Freeradius test mac auth

Tags: freeradius

I have just setup a freeradius server for testing purposes.

I have done a number of tests using PAP, various EAP formats and all went fine.

Now my boss wants me to setup a MAC auth server for internal uses and I have done so following this guide : http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Mac-Auth

My problem now is testing the installation. I can start the server in debug mode with radiusd -X, but now I don't know how to test it. radtest takes username, password and secret as arguments, which are not used in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using NTRadPing for Windows. I haven't found anything for linux yet